# Как добавить новую строку в json-файл, используя python?

Tags: python, json

```
`{
"294047005": {"userNick": "shinoxzu", "userVip": "no"}, 
"174140723": {"userNick": "Anyaka", "userVip": "yes"}, 
"232689205": {"userNick": "foxtoria", "userVip": "no"},
"150408330": {"userNick": "Zhenya", "userVip": "no"}
}`
```

> надо добавить новую, такую же строку, чтобы получилось, например:

```
`{
"294047005": {"userNick": "shinoxzu", "userVip": "no"}, 
"174140723": {"userNick": "Anyaka", "userVip": "yes"}, 
"232689205": {"userNick": "foxtoria", "userVip": "no"},
"162762578": {"userNick": "sasha", "userVip": "yes"},
"150408330": {"userNick": "Zhenya", "userVip": "no"}
}`
```

> также был бы благодарен, если бы рассказали про удаление строки, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете привести JSON к типу данных Dict и работать с ним, как со словарём, а после - привести словарь обратно к JSON-строке

```py
import json

a = '''{
"294047005": {"userNick": "shinoxzu", "userVip": "no"}, 
"174140723": {"userNick": "Anyaka", "userVip": "yes"}, 
"232689205": {"userNick": "foxtoria", "userVip": "no"},
"150408330": {"userNick": "Zhenya", "userVip": "no"}
}'''

# Чтение JSON в словарь из строки
b = json.loads(a) # представление JSON в виде Python-словаря (Dict)
# ... из файла
b = json.load(open('file.json'))

# в этом блоке можно работать с b, как и с любым другим словарём
b.update({"162762578": {"userNick": "sasha", "userVip": "yes"},}) # добавим новое значение
b.pop("232689205", None) # удалим значение по ключу (в данном случае - foxtoria)

# Запись словаря обратно в JSON (в строку)
a = json.dumps(b) 
# ... (в файл)
json.dump(b, open('file.json', 'w'))

print(a)
print(type(a)) # убедимся, что это именно строка (JSON), а не обычный словарь
```

Результат:

```
{"294047005": {"userNick": "shinoxzu", "userVip": "no"}, "174140723": {"userNick": "Anyaka", "userVip": "yes"}, "150408330": {"userNick": "Zhenya", "userVip": "no"}, "162762578": {"userNick": "sasha", "userVip": "yes"}}
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: @shinoxzu виноват, исправил

Comment: большое спасибо!